# Strange behavoir in mariadb: BIGINT UNSIGNED out of range

Tags: select, mariadb, bigint

While debugging a faulty select in our application we stumbled upon a strange behavoir in mariadb10.3.22 and mariadb10.1.

The following query fails:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 9999999999999999999; // 19 digits
```

> ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in 'unix_timestamp() - 9999999999999999999'

However, increasing or decreasing the subtrahend works:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 99999999999999999999; // 20 digits

+-----------------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 99999999999999999999 |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                   -99999999998396888357 |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 999999999999999999; // 18 digits

+---------------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 999999999999999999 |
+---------------------------------------+
|                   -999999998396888251 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Changing the sign of the subtrahend also works:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + -9999999999999999999; // 19 digits

+-----------------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + -9999999999999999999 |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                    -9999999998396886079 |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I also tried to set NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION in sql_mode, but that didn't work either.

Can someone explain that behavoir?

Comment: Should like a bug to report.

Comment: Thanks @marc_s for editing!